# Dispatching clear state action in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using redux in my react project. My question is how to clear state when some works that use state finished.

For example, I have `search` state in my redux store.

```
search:{
  status: 'INIT',
  result: [],
}
```

Since my search is an async request, it has `status` field.

when the user searches a word, it will dispatch 'FETCH_SEARCH' to make status to 'LOADING'.

when fetch done, it will dispatch 'SUCCESS_SEARCH' or 'FAILURE_SEARCH' to make status 'SUCCESS' or 'FAILURE'.

And in my component that shows the result of a search, it renders depend on `search` state's status. If a status is 'SUCCESS', it will render the result of the search.

So far, there is no problem.

but what if the user has searched before and try to search again after some works? Since the user has successfully searched before, `search` state has 'SUCCESS' state. So my component will render 'unwanted' result.

So currently, i dispatch 'CLEAR_SEARCH' action to initialize `search` state.

My question is how to clear redux state after some submission has done.
Am i doing correctly? Or is it anti-pattern?

Comment: The generally accepted pattern when dealing with state in redux, is to have an immutable state. Why do you want to mutate yours?

Comment: @brandNew I think so too.. what about dispatching action something like 'WAIT_SEARCH' that only update status to 'WAITING' when user try to search again? It means a user is waiting for search, different with 'LOADING'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done this before and what I do is follow a workflow.

After a search submission you shouldn't clear state. You should reset it when the user searches again.

Let's say the user searches "Term A". You "SEARCH_SUCCESS" is set and it's rendering the results. When he searches again put that state to "SEARCHING" or "LOADING" as you have it.

Now in your render method if you have something like

```
// etc..

if (isLoading) {
  return <LoadingComponent />
}

// etc..
```

You will render a loading before rendering any results. Then your search action should set either the **SUCCESS** or **FAILURE** and if you have your components mapped out correctly it should be really straightforward.

**EDIT**

After a brief discussion in the comment section you wanted **INIT** only at the start (the first ever time it's rendered) but then resetting the state still.

So you can go for this workflow:

First time:
-> INIT -> SEARCH_TRIGGERED -> LOADING -> SUCCESS or FAILURE

Second time (still in same screen):
-> SEARCH_TRIGGERED -> LOADING -> SUCCESS or FAILURE

And then you would have the desired workflow.

Hope I helped

Comment: Thanks. But I want to render depends on three status.Search tip for 'INIT', Loading for 'LOADING', results for 'SUCCESS'.

Comment: @godsenal What is rendered on INIT? you should have a behaviour in mind

Comment: I want to render search tip when the user just has come to searching page. if it is the first searching, status will be 'INIT'. And after user clicked search button with search word, it will fetch some data with 'LOADING' state.

Comment: @godsenal With what I'm suggesting you can easily accomplish that. INIT is always the start. So on subsequent searches you should say to your store: "Okay he's searching again" and again and again. Always going between LOADING results and SUCESSfully getting those results. INIT is always shown only on start.

Comment: Thanks, but i think i need one more status not LOADING or SUCCESS. because i want to distinguish between 'before type search term' and 'fetching data with search term'. what about put state to 'SEARCHING' when user searches again? So, status can have 'INIT'(shown only on start as you say), 'SEARCHING'(when user try to search), 'LOADING' (get data from some api), 'SUCCESS'(after async api response result)

Comment: @godsenal Yes you can totally do that. I'm gonna update my answer with what you said in the comments

Comment: @godsenal I've done it multiple times. For things like this there is no established pattern. Depends a lot on the tools each one is using and what the requirements are. This solution is really straightforward, good and functional.

Comment: It was very helpful. Thank you again.